# Are there criteria for a scripture to be called an Upanishad?

Tags: upanishads

For example there is a Taittriya Aranyaka and a Taittriya Upanishad and a Taittriya Brahmana.  What criteria allow the Upanishad to be called that?

Comment: The Upanishads were arranged by Vyasa into the different upanishads and he derived them from the vedas. These are the upanishads that are generally recognized as the upanishads. There is, however, no 'rule' as to anyone calling a particular book an 'upanishad'

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26122